# Не запускается Flask сервер

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

имеем самый простой в мире код на фласк(из стандартной документации):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
    

app.run
```

При запуске, казалось бы, все работает. Никаких ошибок не выдает. Но и ничего полезного тоже не происходит: терминал просто думает секунду-другую, и закрывается. Как пофиксить можно ?

Comment: В документации совершенно не такой код. Документация вызывает функцию app.run, а вы не вызываете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в app.run забыл поставить () :d. Вот так и в жизни бывает: ищешь ошибку везде где только можно,  а она у тебя под носом